# Why does my WPF combobox displays Model name that is binded when selected?

Tags: wpf

I have a ComboBox in WPF which I Binded to an observable collection. It was all good. Recently I had to change the background of the combo box and changed the default template of it as per [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24240.changing-the-background-color-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8.aspx?Redirected=true) article

Now the problem is the combo box displays the values that I add to the Observable collection, but when I select an item, it displays the model name. Attached are the pictures

[image]
[image]

XAML Code

```
<ComboBox Width="120" x:Name="cmbMobileCol" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="ColumnName" SelectedValuePath="ColumnLetter" Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxControlTemplate1}"/>
```

Code Behind

```
public ObservableCollection<MobileCol> MobileColList = new ObservableCollection<MobileCol>();

public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  CmbMobileCol.DataContext = this.GetMobileColumns();
}

private void MainWin_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  AddMobileColumns("A", 1);
  AddMobileColumns("B", 2);
  AddMobileColumns("C", 3);
}
```

Combobox Template XAML

```
 <!--#region ComboBox Template Style-->

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                        <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Popup>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="#FFACACAC" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <!--<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1"/>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>-->
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                            </Border.Background>
                                            <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                                <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="F1M0,0L2.667,2.66665 5.3334,0 5.3334,-1.78168 2.6667,0.88501 0,-1.78168 0,0z" Fill="#FF606060" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Border>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFABADB3"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Black"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFEBF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Black"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDAECFC" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDAEBFC" Offset="0"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FFBFBFBF"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="White"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFBFBFBF"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>

                    </ToggleButton.Style>

                </ToggleButton>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" 
                        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                        IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>

            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        </ControlTemplate>

        <!--#endregion-->
```

Comment: I have everything set, please check the XAML and CS code and everything works fine when i remove Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxControlTemplate1}

Comment: Can you share the ComboBoxControlTemplate1 code what is there?

Comment: Added combobox XAML code

Comment: check the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787361/wpf-combobox-default-controltemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ContentTemplateSelector` property of the `ContentPresenter` below the `ToggleButton` and it should work as expected:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" 
                  Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" 
                  ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}"
                  ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                  IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
```